# Label value not set on ComboBox's SelectedIndexChanged (only in one case)

Tags: c#, combobox, label

This is possibly the strangest (and possibly most simple) error I have come across. I have a `ComboBox` with 3 items. Based on the selected index I set the visibility of 3 `PictureBoxes` and a Label's text. The problem is with the latter:

```
private void myCombo_SelectedIndexChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    switch (myCombo.SelectedIndex)
    {
        case 0: // basic
            pictureBoxBasicCampaign.Visible = true;
            pictureBoxApsisCampaign.Visible = false;
            pictureBoxPushCampaign.Visible = false;
            lblCampaignTypeDescription.Text = "Runs or schedules a campaign that writes the recipient data into a file or another database table.";
            break;
        case 1: // apsis
            pictureBoxBasicCampaign.Visible = false;
            pictureBoxApsisCampaign.Visible = true;
            pictureBoxPushCampaign.Visible = false;
            lblCampaignTypeDescription.Text = "Runs or schedules a campaign that sends a newsletter or SMS message to recipients via APSIS.";
            break;
        case 2: // push               
            pictureBoxBasicCampaign.Visible = false;
            pictureBoxApsisCampaign.Visible = false;
            pictureBoxPushCampaign.Visible = true;
            lblCampaignTypeDescription.Text = "Runs or schedules a campaign that sends a push notification to devices running an iOS or Android app.";
            break;   
    }
}
```

Everything works fine! But my `lblCampaignTypeDescription`'s text is not changed ONLY when `SelectedIndex` is 0 and I get an empty label. No exception is thrown and my debug traverses over the `lblCampaignTypeDescription.Text`. But no text. Case 1 and 2 display the text correctly.

Has anyone ever had this issue? Or have I done something stupid?

**Update**:

All references to `lblCampaignTypeDescription` in my project:

```
private MetroFramework.Controls.MetroLabel lblCampaignTypeDescription;

this.lblCampaignTypeDescription = new MetroFramework.Controls.MetroLabel();

this.metroTabPageSelectType.Controls.Add(this.lblCampaignTypeDescription);

// 
// lblCampaignTypeDescription
// 
this.lblCampaignTypeDescription.FontSize = MetroFramework.MetroLabelSize.Small;
this.lblCampaignTypeDescription.FontWeight = MetroFramework.MetroLabelWeight.Regular;
this.lblCampaignTypeDescription.Location = new System.Drawing.Point(121, 261);
this.lblCampaignTypeDescription.Name = "lblCampaignTypeDescription";
this.lblCampaignTypeDescription.Size = new System.Drawing.Size(700, 18);
this.lblCampaignTypeDescription.Style = MetroFramework.MetroColorStyle.Silver;
this.lblCampaignTypeDescription.TabIndex = 11;
this.lblCampaignTypeDescription.Text = "campaign_type_description";
this.lblCampaignTypeDescription.TextAlign = System.Drawing.ContentAlignment.MiddleCenter;
this.lblCampaignTypeDescription.Theme = MetroFramework.MetroThemeStyle.Light;
this.lblCampaignTypeDescription.UseStyleColors = true;
```

The label is a custom label control from `MetroFramework` Winform UI library. But I have been using it a million times and this it the first time this is happening.

Comment: Based on the code you've provided it should work as designed. Is any other place changing the text on the label?

Comment: you could try to call lblCampaignTypeDescription.Update(); I have no idea why your solution is not working.

Comment: Your switch would be better with a "default". Does the text property fail to update in all cases?

Comment: @Bazinga I have added the default case. No the text property only fails to update with the first case (0) and that's why I have been wondering.

Comment: @DaveZych I updated the question with all the references to this label.

Comment: @Pedram, try changing your default case to set the control properties the way you want them to be with the 0 selectedIndex and just leave the zero index case as a fall through to the default case. This could be a potential solution. Also, you could try adding another blank selection for the 0 index to move your other indices up by one, and then create some type of validation to take place to insure a selection other than 0 is made.

Answer (score 0):

When your SelectedIndex changes from 1 to 0 or from 2 to 0 does your lblCampaignTypeDescription.Text changes?Try to show the selectedIndex before other actions.It should be -1 i think

Comment: I did. I added the line `lblCampaignTypeDescription.Text = metroComboBoxManualCampaignType.SelectedIndex.ToString();` before my `switch` statement. The value `0` is simply not displayed. Wonder where the glitch is.